# What is the best Dynamo DB schema to sort results by date?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to create a website for my band where I display our next three upcoming shows. All shows are stored using DynamoDB with three attributes: a date (number that is a unix timestamp), venue (string), and address (string). My first idea was to create a query to return the top 3 results sorted by the date, which I'm used to doing in MySQL. However, it seems sorting can only occur within the same partition, when using a composite key containing a partition_id and a sort_id.

Should I simply put all entries into my table under the same partition_id? This is a very simple website for my band, and it does not need to be performant. However, this seems like an unusual solution in order to simply sort by the date.

I am new to DynamoDB, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to structure my database. Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store your data with a static partition key, as you are only showing a limited amount of data and updates to the data won't exceed more than 1000 RPS.

| PK | SK | VENUE | ADDRESS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-04-05T21:00 | Big Club | Big Town |
| 1 | 2023-05-15T23:00 | Med Club | Med Town |
| 1 | 2023-07-05T21:00 | Festival | New Town |

Now everything is stored in ascending order by date.

To do a request to show your next 3 upcoming shows, it would look like this:

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE PK = 1 AND SK > todays_date_string`

Since you're familiar with SQL you can even use [PartiQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.html) to make the requests in SQL language.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case it's perfectly fine to put everything under same partition ID. As long as you never have two shows with the exactly same date you can use some constant value as a hash key and date as a sort key.

Having a single partition would be a problem if your read or write throughput exceed single partition limits (~ 3000 RPS / 1000 WPS), but I suspect it's not the case for you.